# What do these ramp markings mean at KIFP?

Tags: airport, airport-markings

As a pilot, what do I need to know about these ramp markings at [KIFP](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KIFP)? Are they operationally significant?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

They are helicopter parking markers, [as per the AC that defines them:](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5390_2c.pdf)

[image]

I was never taught about this in my training and it was not on the fixed wing PPL exam nor is it on the [FAA's quick reference guide](https://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/publications/media/Pilots_Guide_to_Airport_Signs_and_Markings.pdf) but its a good idea to know what they are.

Although interestingly they are not where the airport diagram denotes the "Helicopter Parking"

[image]